# The graph of the function $f(x)= \left\{ \frac{1}{2 x} \right\}- \frac{1}{2}\left\{ \frac{1}{x} \right\} $ for $0<x<1$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, reference-request, graphing-functions, fractional-part

Let for reals 
 $$\{x\}=\text{Frac}(x)$$ the [fractional part function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalPart.html), take for example  the more common definition, the first (there is a different definition as you see in this **MathWorld's Page**, from Graham et alumni). Thus I know that $$\text{Frac}(x)=x$$ for $0<x<1$.

I am interesting in basics about the graphic representation of some of the following functions for a fixed real $0<\lambda<1$, 
$$f_\lambda(x)= \left\{ \frac{\lambda}{ x} \right\}- \lambda\left\{ \frac{1}{x} \right\}  $$
for $0<x<1$.

I am stuck because it is a difficult function, I don't know if there is good references in this site or in the literature to study some aspect of this kind of functions. Please add in your answer or in comments useful posts in this site.

> **Question.** Can you explain us the graphic (or at least the more relevant facts) of the function $$f(x)= \left\{ \frac{1}{2 x} \right\}- \frac{1}{2}\left\{ \frac{1}{x} \right\}  $$
>   for $0<x<1$. You can add your computations and draws that you want explain to get a good reference for this family of functions from this example $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$. **Thanks in advance.**

My code for [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) were first

$\text{Frac(1/(2x))     for  0<x<1 }$

(respectively with $\text{(1/2 )Frac(1/x)}$ ) and after

$\text{Frac(1/(2x)) -(1/2 )Frac(1/x)     for  0<x<1 }$.

Like this: It is possible an explanation of how get such difference between 
arcs of *hyperbolas*?, or,  are there infinitely many 
*straight segments* in the graph of our $f(x)$?, or can you obtain a closed-form for such difference of hyperbolas as a constant (those straight segments in the graph of our $f(x)$)?...this was my **Question**.

Comment: I've typed the code as a formula in TEX, because the plain text didn't showed all the text.

Comment: I hope positive votes for the users that answered my question, because they have the merit. Very thanks much all users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us write down $\frac 1 x = n + f$, where $n\in\mathbb N_0$, $0\leq f < 1$, and let us consider two cases:

*Case 1.* $n = 2k$, $k\in\mathbb N_0$

We have $\frac 1 x = 2k + f$ and $\frac 1 {2x} = k + \frac f 2$, thus $f(x) =\left\{\frac 1 {2x} \right\} - \frac 1 2\left\{ \frac 1 {x}\right\} = \frac f 2 - \frac f 2 = 0$.

*Case 2.* $n = 2k+1$, $k\in\mathbb N_0$

We have $\frac 1 x = 2k + 1 + f$ and $\frac 1 {2x} = k + \frac {f+1} 2$, thus $f(x) =\left\{\frac 1 {2x} \right\} - \frac 1 2\left\{ \frac 1 {x}\right\} = \frac {f+1} 2 - \frac f 2 = \frac 1 2$.

Now,

$$f(x) = 0\iff 2k\leq \frac 1 x < 2k+1 \iff x\in\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N}\left\langle \frac 1 {2k+1},\frac 1 {2k}\right]$$

$$f(x) = \frac 1 2\iff 2k-1\leq \frac 1 x < 2k \iff x\in\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N}\left\langle \frac 1 {2k},\frac 1 {2k-1}\right]$$

so we conclude that $f$ is a half of the indicator function of the set $\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N}\left\langle \frac 1 {2k},\frac 1 {2k-1}\right]$.

Since the length of interval $\left\langle \frac 1 {n+1},\frac 1 n\right]$ is $\frac 1 n - \frac 1{n+1} = \frac 1 {n(n+1)}$, $f$ changes from $\frac 1 2$ to $0$ and back to $\frac 1 2$ approximately at the rate of $\frac 1{n^2}$ approaching $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

---

Let us consider case of $\lambda = \frac 1 m$, for fixed $m\in\mathbb N$ and let $l\equiv \lfloor \frac 1 x\rfloor \pmod m$.

We have $\frac 1 x = mk + l + f$, $0\leq f < 1$ and consequently $$f_{\frac 1 m}(x)= \left\{ \frac 1 {mx}\right\} - \frac 1m\left\{\frac 1 x\right\} = \frac{f+l}m - \frac fm = \frac l m$$

Comment: Very thanks much **Ennar**, I've read your proof and understand all details, very thanks much. Now your computations are a reference for all user of this site. I will pay the bounty in 22 hours. Very thanks much one more time and good summetime.

Comment: @user243301, you are welcome. You may also want to consider the answer by Christian Blatter for bounty, as it is more general than mine.

Comment: I accept your words about Blatter's answer, but I've consider put in your hands the prize. Very thans much for your early answer and the valuable answer of Blatter, that now are a reference for all users for this question.

Comment: @user243301, thank you for the bounty. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 2):

In order to visualize what's happening put $x:={1\over y}$  and consider the functions
$$g_\lambda(y):=\{\lambda y\}-\lambda\{y\}=\lambda\lfloor y\rfloor-\lfloor\lambda y\rfloor\qquad(y>1)$$
instead. They satisfy
$$-\lambda<g_\lambda(y)<1\ ,\tag{1}$$
have jump discontinuities at the integer points $k\geq2$ and at the points ${k\over\lambda}$  $(k\geq1)$, and are constant between two consecutive jumps. If $\lambda={p\over q}$ is rational then $g_\lambda$ is periodic with period $q$, but if $\lambda$ is irrational there is no periodic behavior. The figure below shows $g_\lambda$ for $\lambda:={\sqrt{5}-1\over2}$.

It follows that the functions $x\mapsto f_\lambda(x)$ have isolated jump discontinuities accumulating at $0$, and that $f_\lambda$ is constant within the bounds $(1)$ between successive jumps.

[image]

Comment: Very thanks much! Now I am reading all your valuable statements. You and users as Ennar do possible this MathStack Exchange.