# A basis for $\text{span}_{L^2(0,1)} \left\{ \eta_\alpha,0<\alpha<1 \right\}$, and how compute coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, wavelets

Let $$\text{span}_{L^2(0,1)} \left\{ \eta_\alpha,0<\alpha<1 \right\},$$ where we take $$\eta_\alpha(t)= \left\{ \frac{\alpha}{t} \right\} -\alpha \left\{  \frac{1}{t} \right\},$$ and $ \left\{ x \right\} $ is the **fractional part function**.

Previous is a closed and convex subset of the **Hilbert space** $L^2(0,1)$.

This set $\text{span}_{L^2(0,1)} \left\{ \eta_\alpha,0<\alpha<1 \right\}$ is famed because is related with an unsolver problem (see here in the page 345 this [Notices of The AMS](http://www.ams.org/notices/200303/fea-conrey-web.pdf),  The Riemann Hypothesis, by **Conrey**).

I would like to explore more easy facts of this space and their elements.

> **Question 1.** What 's a good basis to explore this linear subspace of $L^2(0,1)$?

I say that since previous subset is defined as a subspace spanned, I would like to know a good basis to try explore questions about this subspace and their elements from the viewpoint of the real analysis and functional analysis (my main purpose is refresh issues of this theories). I thought in the trygonometric system or the [Haar system for the unit interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet), but notice that in this article from the **Wikipedia's Page**, the unit interval is the closed set $ \left[ 0,1 \right] $ (do a comparison with the open set  $\left( 0,1 \right) $) of $L^2(0,1)$. I don't understand well previous cited unsolved problem to know if the fact to declare a such basis implies the thesis, (this is the veracity of such identity between spaces showed in page 345 of previous article) in any case I need a basis to do computations.

**A main problem is that $\alpha$ is in an uncountable set,** and I don't know what can I do with this subspace to put a basis in it. **Or if the right is put a basis in the underlying Hilbert space** $L^2(0,1)$.

My next question is if you want to provide to me a easy example of how do you compute the coordinates of the more easy function in this span endowed with the basis that you've choosen. In this [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820052/the-graph-of-the-function-fx-left-frac12-x-right-frac12-lef) you've the answer of another of my previous of  questions, that provide us easy examples of such functions.

> **Question 2.** Compute the coordinates of $\eta_{\frac{1}{2}}(t)$ in the basis that you've choosen in previous question. **Thanks in advance.**

I want to refresh these notions, and improve my abilities in real and functional analysis in the next season.

Comment: I believe that one of the references that is germ of the idea of the **approach of Nymann-Beurling**, as is named in previous paper, is as I said I believe **Beurling, A closure problem related with the Riemann-Zeta function** Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. 41, 312–314, (1955).

Comment: you know the Fourier series $\{x\} = \frac{1}{2} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2 \pi n x)}{\pi n}$ (used to prove the functional equation for $\zeta(s) = -s\int_0^\infty \{x\} x^{-s-1} dx$)  so your family $\eta_\alpha$ is a basis of $span(\{\sin(2 \pi n t)\}) \cap L^2([0,1])$ can you prove it ? Let $s_n(t) = \sin(2 \pi n t)$, if $h = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n s_n$, can you find $a_n$ such that $h =\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \eta_{2 \pi n}$ ? (where both series are meant to converge in $L^2([0,1])$)

Comment: I know the first identity, I don't know your second claim. And the third I don't undetand what do you want say, since you say that the family $\eta_\alpha$ **is a basis of...** when I undersand that a family is a basis of a linear space. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your claims, and very thanks much @user1952009

Comment: you know that $L^2([0,1])$ is isomorphic to the set of Fourier series $\sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty C_n e^{2 i \pi n t}$ with $\sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty |C_n|^2 <\infty$ ? (i.e $(C_n) \in l^2(\mathbb{Z})$).  If you replace $e^{2 i \pi nt}$ by $\sin(2 \pi n t)$ you get the subspace of  odd functions of $L^2([0,1])$, isomorphic to $L^2([0,1/2])$

Comment: When one want to find $a_n$ need to multiply (the scalar product) with an element orthogonal/orthonormal with the others $m\neq n$, isn it @user1952009

Comment: only when the family is orthogonal, here the $\eta_\alpha$ family is not orthogonal

Comment: Very thanks much then, I think in your claims, I know that $L^2[0,1]$ is isomorphic to the set of previous Fourier series with coefficients in $l^2$ as your said. Very thanks much for all your claims, your help is always aprecciated @user1952009